# Nuxtjs 3 - Cannot read properties of undefined using reactive()

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I'm having a problem with a reactive() object, an error is generated when trying to use the no template.

FormInterface

```
    export interface FormInterface {
      nome?: string
      endereco?: Endereco
      
    }
    interface Endereco {
      cep?: string
    }
```

---

```
let ruleForm = reactive<FormInterface>({})
```

Template

```
<template>
<div>
<span> {{ ruleForm.endereco.cep }} </span>
</div>
</template>
```

Erro
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cep')

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved

```
let ruleForm = reactive<FormInterface>({endereco:{}})
```